# Prove that a function is in "Big-O"

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Prove that $f(h)=h^2+5h^{17}$ is in $O(h^2)$.

I don't understand this problem. Big O notation continues to befuddle me. I *think* that what I need to show is that there exists a constant $C$ such that $|f(h)|\leq C|h|^2$ for $h$ "sufficiently small."

Does this mean $h$ must be almost equal to $0$? If that is so, I think I can prove it, since $5h^{17}<5h^2$ when $|h|<1$.

But honestly, I don't know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct: $f(h) \in O(h^k)$ as $h \to 0$ if and only if there exists $M$ and $\epsilon$ such that $|f(h)| \leq M|h|^k$ whenever $|h| < \epsilon$.  Your observation implies that $|f(h)| \leq 6h^2$ whenever $|h| \leq 1$.